# How to stop animation in React and Css on load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created a card with a button. When you click the button I want the picture on the card to fade away to the left and have text come in from the right. When clicked again I want the text to fade away to the left and the image to come back from the right. However, with the way I have it set up the animation plays on load causing the image to move to the left then style correctly. How can I fix this?

```
<div className="col-md-6" >
            <div className={this.props.bg}>
                <div className="turnButton-left" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <i className="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>
                </div>
                <div className="project-title">
                    {this.props.title}
                </div>
                <div className="project-image">
                    {!this.props.flipped ?
                        <img className="{!this.props.flipped ? "fadeInRight" : "fadeOutLeft"}" src={this.props.image} alt=""/> :
                        <div className={`reverse-card px-3 ${this.props.flipped ? "fadeInRight" : "fadeOutLeft"}`}>
                            <span className="involvement">My Role</span>
                                <span className="supportingText mb-3">{this.props.role}</span>
                            <span className="involvement">Languages Used</span>
                                <span className="supportingText mb-3">{this.props.language}</span>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div className="project-button">
                    <a href={this.props.site}><div className="to-top color-blue"><i className="fas fa-globe"></i> Visit Site</div></a>
                    <a href={this.props.code}><div className="to-top color-blue"><i className="fas fa-code-branch"></i> View Code</div></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you put up a demo on [CodeSandBox React](https://codesandbox.io/s/y2lrywpk21), it would be easier to visualize your problem that way.

Comment: here it is https://y1dp5.csb.app/